# Excel VBA Run time error 6 when assigning value to cell

Tags: excel, vba, overflow

A subroutine that I have used for a long time has stopped working for some reason. The simplified macro below causes a "run time error '6': Overflow" when I try to assign a value to a cell. The value in cell C2 is assigned to cValue but the error occurs when it is set in cell C3.

```vb
Private AWB As Workbook
Private cValue As Double

Sub Test()

    Set AWB = ThisWorkbook
    Sheets("Import").Select

    Range("C2").Select
    cValue = ActiveCell.Value

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = cValue

End Sub
```

Comment: I apologize, the above should have been in code. I have tried to add do it correctly but have not been able to turn it into code

Comment: An overflow error indicates that whatever value you are setting is beyond the allowable range for that data type. What is the value of `cValue`? Is the cell (C3 in this case) formatted as text, integer, date, etc?

Comment: Use `Value2` instead of `Value`

Comment: Cell C2 is 125.2 and Cell C3 is formatted as a number.

Comment: Could you share why it is necessary that `AWB` and `cValue` are declared outside the procedure, especially the workbook?

Comment: I tried cValue = ActiveCell.value2 and get the same error.

Comment: This is a group of procedures that I simplified to try and focus on the problem. Both AWB and cValue are used in other procedures and, in fact, cValue is actually obtained by a data query from a data source called Alphavantage

Comment: If `cValue` is obtained, why are you writing the value from `C2` to it? Couldn't you just write from `C2` to `C3` without the use of `cValue`? What exactly is obtained?

Comment: I tried to simplify the routine even more by setting a value for cValue and then having a line cValue = cValue + 1. This also causes a runtime error.

Comment: VBasic2008 - This is a simplified example. The value in cValue actually comes from a cell on another sheet that is deleted once the value is obtained.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Solution1()

    'Set AWB = ThisWorkbook
    
    With Worksheets("Import").Range("C2")
        cValue = .Value2
        .Offset(1, 0).Value2 = cValue
    End With
    
End Sub
    ' *** <OR> ***
Sub Solution2()
    With Worksheets("Import").Range("C2")
        .Offset(1, 0).Value2 = .Value2
    End With
End Sub
```

If you still run into trouble, try changing your `cValue` type to `as variant`.

Comment: Solution1 gave the same error but Solution2 worked.  Unfortunately, I oversimplified my routine so I do not see how I can use Solution2. I have a variable cValue that is passed from another routine. It has a value (125.5 in my example) and I need to assign this value to a cell that I select. Before now, I would use ActiveCell.Offset().Select to move to this cell and then use ActiveCell.Value = cValue.   In the watch window, cValue is 125.5 before this step and then becomes 0 & I get an error.  Something is wrong with how I am using the ActiveCell.Value syntax but I do not understand what.

Comment: Ah okay, Try Solution 1 but make sure to change `Private cValue As Double` to `Private cValue as Variant`. Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: The use of Variant instead of Double worked. Thanks!

Comment: Good, if you want to optimize your code, you might want to figure out why your data doesn't fit a `double` data type, then find a way to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Cell Value

- If you're dealing with the workbook containing this code, specify it with `ThisWorkbook` where ever you need it. If it's in a hundred procedures, do it a hundred times.
- Using variables outside of procedures is kind of a last resort when you can't handle things differently, not to write fewer characters.
- Qualify your objects by using variables (instead of using `Select` or any flavors of *Active*) to avoid long, unreadable expressions like e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import").Range("C2").Offset(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import").Range("C2").Value` which you could actually use instead of the posted code (not recommended).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Import")
    
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = ws.Range("C2")
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = sCell.Offset(1)
    
    dCell.Value = sCell.Value
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your routine and it works. My problem is that cValue comes from another routine that does a query form a site. This query returns a cvs file that needs to be formatted and then sorted to find the value. No way to know what cell it will be in - this has to be determined by a search. Once done, I set the value of cValue and return it to the main routine. From the watch, the value is returned but the error occurs when I try to do anything with cValue.